# Make WebClient().DownloadString async

Tags: c#, async-await

How i can make this code non-blocking **async** so it doesn't block the UI? do i need to use another library ?

```
public static double GetRsi(string symbol1, string interval1, string period1)
            {
                //API KEY FROM alphavantage.co
                string API_KEY = "xxxxxxx";
                
                StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                urlBuilder.Append($"https://www.alphavantage.co/");
                urlBuilder.Append($"query?function=RSI&symbol={symbol1}&interval={interval1}&time_period={period1}&series_type=open&apikey={API_KEY}");
                string jsonData = new WebClient().DownloadString(urlBuilder.ToString());
    
    
                var machine = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlphavantageData>(jsonData);
                var _RSI = machine.TechnicalAnalysisRsi.Last().Value.Rsi;
                return _RSI; 
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebClient` has a [DownloadStringTaskAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync?view=netcore-3.1) that you can use:

```
public static async Task<double> GetRsi(string symbol1, string interval1, string period1)
{
    //API KEY FROM alphavantage.co
    string API_KEY = "xxxxxxx";
    
    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    urlBuilder.Append($"https://www.alphavantage.co/");
    urlBuilder.Append($"query?function=RSI&symbol={symbol1}&interval={interval1}&time_period={period1}&series_type=open&apikey={API_KEY}");
    
    using(var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        string jsonData = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(urlBuilder.ToString());

        var machine = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AlphavantageData>(jsonData);
        var _RSI = machine.TechnicalAnalysisRsi.Last().Value.Rsi;
        return _RSI; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It's return "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Double]", how i can access the double data ?

Comment: You need to await the call: var value = `await GetRsi(...);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DownloadStringTaskAsync` as was already suggested.
I also wanted to mention that using `WebClient` is not recommended in the modern C#/.NET code. Try `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` instead. It's lighter and is `async` from the get go.

Please, check out [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1).

Example:

```
// You need 1 client per application
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

...
var url = $"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=RSI&symbol={symbol1}&interval={interval1}&time_period={period1}&series_type=open&apikey={API_KEY}";
var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

Comment: It's return "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Double]", how i can access the double data ?

Comment: @user13877792 `GetStringAsync` returns Task<double>? I'm sure it returning string.

Comment: Are you using `await` operator?